# Check remote repository for sha1

Tags: git

What is the most resource/network efficient command to check if the remote repository contains the <'sha1'>?

Is doing

```
git fetch
git branch -r --contains <sha1> | grep <branch>
```

the only way to perform this check?

There is also this option:

```
git ls-remote <repository URL><project> <refspec>
```

Is there a way to use this to perform the check in question? Would it be more efficient? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

`git ls-remote` only gives you remote heads.  So it's a start, but we're far from "any sha-1".

It seems like it's possible with `git fetch`, though it's obvious it wasn't written with that task in mind:

```
$ git fetch origin <sha1 that exists in remote>
From git.remote.org:path/to/repo
 * branch            28e9bb33a769d80f60a4c06a04b49179a34acc77 -> FETCH_HEAD
$ echo $?
0

$ git fetch origin <sha1 that doesn't exist in remote>
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. This does solve the question with getting confident about the existence of sha1 in remote repo, but this is the slowest/resource expensive way: get everything from remote and then check.

Git can almost make you a cup of hot coffee in the morning. I just can't believe that there is no way to perform the check in question without actually fetching remote updates...

Comment: I do have to ask: why would you need such a feature?

Comment: You do not take everything out of a fridge just to see if there's milk in it right? There is a need to make retries until a certain change appears in repository's mirror. The project is large enough to have new changes on each retry - which would result in multiple fetches. This is too inefficient and these operations appear heavy.. at least to me. git ls-remote takes 7 seconds.

Comment: I'd assume `git fetch` did the smart thing with regard what to fetch, but not to the point of notifying you when to try. Good luck!

Comment: thanks. I solved my particular problem by using gerrit replication events, since my CI is configured to populate them. This has no load on servers / network or anything. Haven't found anything better than git fetch if going the 'git' way.